# Create ranges of minutes (15) in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a select which brings me beyond the results of the table a column with a range of 15 minutes.

What I am trying to do, is to group hours between 00:00 and 00:15 in a 0:15 range. 
After grouping the registers between 0:16 and 0:30 in a 0:30 range. This I will do for all hours in a day.

Below, I describe my select. If someone can help me develop a line of thought. Tks a lot.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "ARADMIN"."GSC_VW_INC_DIARIOS"("ID_INCIDENTE", "STATUS_INCIDENTE", "DATAHORA_CRIACAO", "DATA_CRIACAO",       "HORA_CRIACAO", "PRIORIDADE", "IMPACTO", "URGÊNCIA")
AS
 SELECT T2318.C1,
CASE (T2318.C7)
  WHEN 0
  THEN 'NOVO'
  WHEN 1
  THEN 'DESIGNADO'
  WHEN 2
  THEN 'EM ANDAMENTO'
  WHEN 3
  THEN 'PENDENTE'
  WHEN 4
  THEN 'RESOLVIDO'
  WHEN 5
  THEN 'FECHADO'
  WHEN 6
  THEN 'CANCELADO'
END,
TO_CHAR(secs_to_datetime(T2318.C3),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_CHAR(secs_to_date(T2318.C3),'DD/MM/YYYY'),
CASE TO_CHAR(secs_to_hour(T2318.C3),'HH24:MI')
  WHEN TO_CHAR(secs_to_hour(T2318.C3),'HH24:MI') BETWEEN ('00:00' AND '00:15')
  THEN '00:15'
END,
CASE (T2318.C1000000164)
  WHEN 0
  THEN 'CRÍTICO'
  WHEN 1
  THEN 'ALTO'
  WHEN 2
  THEN 'MÉDIO'
  WHEN 3
  THEN 'BAIXO'
END,
CASE (T2318.C1000000163)
  WHEN 1000
  THEN 'EXTENSIVO/DIFUNDIDO'
  WHEN 2000
  THEN 'SIGNIFICATIVO/GRANDE'
  WHEN 3000
  THEN 'MODERADO/LIMITADO'
  WHEN 4000
  THEN 'MENOR/LOCALIZADO'
END,
CASE (T2318.C1000000162)
  WHEN 1000
  THEN 'CRÍTICO'
  WHEN 2000
  THEN 'ALTO'
  WHEN 3000
  THEN 'MÉDIO'
  WHEN 4000
  THEN 'BAIXO'
END
  FROM T2318
  WHERE T2318.C3 > 1434419999;
```

To ilustrate what I am trying. I will paste the print of select result

[image: Result of Select]

Comment: Get the minutes and divide by 15, use that number to group by.

Comment: I do not understood.

Comment: Get the number on minutes from midnight, and divide that amount by 15, that will group the records in 15 minute intervals.

Comment: What's the datatype of `HORA_CRIACAO`?

Comment: The column hora_criacao is a number

Comment: @Barcat - `01:10` is a number? The underlying T2318.C3 seems to be a number - I guess seconds since 1970?

Comment: I misread that first line as part of the select because I didn't immediately realize that the Oracle view syntax handles the columns names that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're starting with a date value, or in this case a value that has been converted to a date, you can find which 15 minute block of the day it belongs to be manipulating the number of seconds past midnight; which you can get from `to_char()` with the `SSSSS` format model.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as now_time,
  to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS') as now_secs
from dual;

NOW_TIME            NOW_S
------------------- -----
2015-06-18 18:25:49 66349
```

You can round the the number of seconds down to the start of a 15-minute period by dividing by 900 (15 * 60), truncating or flooring it to get an integer value, and multiply back by 900:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as now_time,
  to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS') as now_secs,
  to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS'))/900 as calc1,
  floor(to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS'))/900) as calc2,
  floor(to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS'))/900) * 900 as calc3
from dual;

NOW_TIME            NOW_S      CALC1      CALC2      CALC3
------------------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
2015-06-18 18:25:49 66349 73.7211111         73      65700
```

And you can convert that back to a time by adding it back to a date:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as now_time,
  to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS') as now_secs,
  floor(to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS'))/900) * 900 as calc3,
  to_char(date '1970-01-01'
    + (floor(to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'SSSSS'))/900) * 900 / 86400),
    'HH24:MI:SS') as calc4
from dual;

NOW_TIME            NOW_S      CALC3 CALC4  
------------------- ----- ---------- --------
2015-06-18 18:25:49 66349      65700 18:15:00
```

You probably want to preserve the date though, so you can add it to `trunc(<original_date>)` instead. Unless you only have data within a single day, or want to show the same time from multiple days bundled together, I suppose.

Here's a demo with 10 randomly-generated times, showing the 15-minute block they're assigned to:

```
with t (date_field) as (
  select sysdate - dbms_random.value(0, 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
select to_char(date_field, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as datefield,
  to_char(date_field, 'SSSSS') as time_secs,
  floor(to_number(to_char(date_field, 'SSSSS'))/900) * 900
    as fifteen_min_block_secs,
  to_char(trunc(date_field)
    + (floor(to_number(to_char(date_field, 'SSSSS'))/900) * 900) / 86400,
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as fifteen_min_block
from t
order by datefield;

DATEFIELD           TIME_ FIFTEEN_MIN_BLOCK_SECS FIFTEEN_MIN_BLOCK 
------------------- ----- ---------------------- -------------------
2015-06-17 21:03:00 75780                  75600 2015-06-17 21:00:00
2015-06-18 05:07:28 18448                  18000 2015-06-18 05:00:00
2015-06-18 05:48:42 20922                  20700 2015-06-18 05:45:00
2015-06-18 07:23:03 26583                  26100 2015-06-18 07:15:00
2015-06-18 08:24:57 30297                  29700 2015-06-18 08:15:00
2015-06-18 08:52:06 31926                  31500 2015-06-18 08:45:00
2015-06-18 10:59:14 39554                  38700 2015-06-18 10:45:00
2015-06-18 11:47:05 42425                  42300 2015-06-18 11:45:00
2015-06-18 12:08:37 43717                  43200 2015-06-18 12:00:00
2015-06-18 17:07:23 61643                  61200 2015-06-18 17:00:00
```

So you'd need to have the

```
trunc(date_field)
  + (floor(to_number(to_char(date_field, 'SSSSS'))/900) * 900) / 86400
```

or the slightly simpler

```
trunc(date_field)
  + floor(to_number(to_char(date_field, 'SSSSS'))/900) / 96
```

part in your `group by` clause, and probably in your select list for display.

---

Assuming T2318.C3 is seconds since the epoch, you could manipulate that directly and then pass that to your `secs_to_datetime` function:

```
secs_to_datetime(floor(T2318.C3 / 900) * 900)
```

So the equivalent demo to the one above, again with ten randomly-generated times in a CTE, would be:

```
with T2318(c3) as (
  select 1434708000 - dbms_random.value(0, 80000) from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
select to_char(secs_to_datetime(T2318.C3),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as datefield,
  T2318.C3 as time_secs,
  floor(T2318.C3/900) * 900 as fifteen_min_secs,
  to_char(secs_to_datetime(floor(T2318.C3 / 900) * 900),
    'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as fifteen_min
from T2318
order by T2318.C3;

DATEFIELD              TIME_SECS FIFTEEN_MIN_SECS FIFTEEN_MIN       
------------------- ------------ ---------------- -------------------
18/06/2015 12:34:02   1434630842       1434630600 18/06/2015 12:30:00
18/06/2015 15:06:25   1434639985       1434639600 18/06/2015 15:00:00
18/06/2015 16:43:27   1434645807       1434645000 18/06/2015 16:30:00
18/06/2015 18:57:25   1434653845       1434653100 18/06/2015 18:45:00
18/06/2015 19:01:09   1434654069       1434654000 18/06/2015 19:00:00
18/06/2015 20:54:09   1434660849       1434660300 18/06/2015 20:45:00
19/06/2015 03:59:48   1434686388       1434685500 19/06/2015 03:45:00
19/06/2015 06:58:09   1434697089       1434696300 19/06/2015 06:45:00
19/06/2015 07:36:36   1434699396       1434699000 19/06/2015 07:30:00
19/06/2015 07:47:26   1434700046       1434699900 19/06/2015 07:45:00
```

Or if it's in milliseconds, divide and multiply by 900000.

Comment: Hello Alex, tks for your help.
I used your suggestion and the most part works ok, only the third line show problem.

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(T2318.C3) + (floor(to_number(TO_CHAR(T2318.C3))/900) * 900) / 86400, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS fifteen_min_block

After modify the line, the select return erro (below)
ORA-01481: modelo inválido para formato de número
01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.

Comment: The select was as follow:
SELECT TO_CHAR(secs_to_datetime(T2318.C3),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS datefield,
TO_CHAR(T2318.C3) AS time_secs,
  floor(to_number(TO_CHAR(T2318.C3))/900) *  900 AS fifteen_min_block_secs, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(T2318.C3) + (floor(to_number(TO_CHAR(T2318.C3))/900) * 900) / 86400, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS fifteen_min_block
FROM T2318
ORDER BY datefield;

Comment: @Barcat - if you're using the epoch time (?) in T2318.C3 directly, not converting it to a DATE type first, then you're confusing the two parts of the answer. You're also doing more conversions than you need to. I've added a more complete version of the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL when we talk about "grouping" we are most often talking about aggregating multiple rows together and summarizing the result. I get the impression that you just want to "round" time values down to the start of a 15-minute block. The math is pretty easy but you may still have a little work to get it to display he way you want it:

```
FLOOR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime_column) / 15) * 15
```

or maybe:

```
'00:' || RIGHT('0' || TO_CHAR(FLOOR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime_column) / 15) * 15), 2)
```

I'm not sure if you truly have a datetime column to work with but it's not much different against a string value in a known format.

```
FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(RIGHT(HORA_CRIACAO, 2)) / 15) * 15
```

I wanted to use integer division but I'm not quite sure how that's accomplished in Oracle. Many people are surprised by that behavior though so it's possible that using `FLOOR()` is more clear anyway.

Comment: You'd need to add that to the original date's hour though, not a fixed `00:`; just the minutes aren't very useful? e.g. in Oracle, `trunc(datetime_column, 'HH24')` to get the start of the hour; then add the 0/15/30/45 minutes back on. And just to make it slightly more difficult, you can't `extract` minutes from a DATE in Oracle, only from a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Well a date doesn't have a time component... I know what you're talking about with the display of hours but I'm really not sure what OP is wanting to see. That part can be replaced with a date format expression without even truncating.

Comment: A date does have a time component in Oracle. (DATAHORA_CRIACAO in the example). But agree it's not very clear what is needed.

Comment: Ok. I'm not as familiar with the Oracle types. And now I see that the last sample output is one that doesn't start with "00:".