# Grouping set of data by 15 minutes intervals

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get an average amount of sessions established to our internal company system. The problem is that the scope is about three months backwards and I would like to group this whole set of large data by 15 minutes interval, so the output will be like:

```
interval      sess_avg
12:00-12:15   300
12:15-12:30   350
etc..
```

My query is:

```
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(sess_start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') time_start,
        COUNT (sess_id) how_many
                FROM
        t.sessions,
        t.users
            WHERE
        t.users.user_id         =t.sessions.sess_user_id
        AND user_type     !='X'
        AND sess_start_date>=TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12))
GROUP BY
        TO_CHAR(sess_start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to start. Please, help.

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30920975/266304). Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21238990/266304), but the situation there is more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30920975/266304), you can use the SSSSS format model to manipulate the time part of your date values. Applying that method here, you can then query and group by that adjusted value:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sess_start_date)
            + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96,
        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') time_start,
    COUNT (sess_id) how_many
FROM
    t.sessions,
    t.users
WHERE
    t.users.user_id = t.sessions.sess_user_id
    AND user_type !='X'
    AND sess_start_date>=TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12))
GROUP BY
    TRUNC(sess_start_date) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96;
```

If you want the time periods without reference to the date you can instead do:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900,
      'SSSSS'),'HH24:MI') time_start,
    COUNT (sess_id) how_many
FROM
    t.sessions,
    t.users
WHERE
    t.users.user_id = t.sessions.sess_user_id
    AND user_type !='X'
    AND sess_start_date>=TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12))
GROUP BY
    TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS');
```

To get the average count across the same period for all days, you can combine them, with an inline view:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(period_start, 'HH24:MI') as period_start,
    AVG (how_many) avg_how_many
FROM (
  SELECT
      TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900,
          'SSSSS') period_start,
      TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sess_start_date)
              + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96,
          'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') time_start,
      COUNT (sess_id) how_many
  FROM
      t.sessions,
      t.users
  WHERE
      t.users.user_id = t.sessions.sess_user_id
      AND user_type !='X'
      AND sess_start_date>=TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12))
  GROUP BY
      TO_DATE(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)*900, 'SSSSS'),
      TRUNC(sess_start_date) + FLOOR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sess_start_date, 'SSSSS'))/900)/96
)
GROUP BY
    period_start
ORDER BY
    period_start;
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the /900/96 division. How did you arrive on that?

Comment: @ArthurAccioly - I really had to think about that; the 96 part anyway. 900 is the number of seconds in 15 minutes (15*60). 96 is the number of 15-minute periods in a day (24*4). The older question I linked to at the start shows that as a simplification of a calculation based on 86400 seconds in a day (900*96 = 86400).

Comment: Actually it's probably worth looking at [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921930/266304) anyway, as this one is a follow-on that skips explanation of a lot of the logic.

Comment: With Daylight Savings, answers with hardcoded 96's are wrong twice a year

Comment: Yes, but this is dealing with dates, which are not time zone aware, so you can't really do anything about that.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT
        TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12)) + 
         floor((sess_start_date - TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12)))*24*4)/24/4 time_start,
        COUNT (sess_id) as how_many
FROM
        t.sessions,
        t.users
WHERE
        t.users.user_id         =t.sessions.sess_user_id
        AND user_type     !='X'
        AND sess_start_date>=TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12))
GROUP BY
        floor((sess_start_date - TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12)))*24*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote this generic function:

```
FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;
```

In your case you would use this function like

```
...
GROUP BY MakeInterval(sess_start_date, INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
```

Note, the function raises an error if the interval "does not fit", e.g. `MakeInterval(sess_start_date, INTERVAL '16' MINUTE)`, i.e. valid intervals are

- `INTERVAL '1' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '2' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '3' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '4' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '6' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '8' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '12' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '24' HOUR`
- `INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '2' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '3' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '4' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '5' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '6' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '10' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '12' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '15' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '20' MINUTE`
- `INTERVAL '30' MINUTE`
- etc.