# How can i group by 15 minute interval in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanna group a data by 15 minutes intervals and left show the amount of values from that interval, something like that

```
  hora     sum(valor)
--12:15 -- 4.980,00
--12:30 -- 15.190,00
--12:45 -- 4.010,00
```

hora is a varchar type and valor is a number type.

I have blocked my mind but i have this:

```
SELECT 
HORA,
SUM(VALOR)
FROM INFORMACION
GROUP BY 
FECHA, 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(HORA, 'HH24:MI'), 'MI')) * 15
ORDER BY FECHA, HORA
```

thanks for help

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  Why do you need to cast `FECHA`?  What are the data types?

Comment: I did the changes

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284271/grouping-set-of-data-by-15-minutes-intervals/40285359#40285359

Comment: I have to do it only in sql

Comment: Then use `TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)) * EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM INTERVAL '15' MINUTE) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE` or shorter `TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / 15) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE;`

Comment: Look [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9535737800346722891) might help

Comment: Looks like you want for any hour the data to be bucketed into 4 time stamps from 00 to 15, 16 to 30,31 to 45 and 45 to 59. If it is that way then you can pick up the minute part from the Varchar field which has the minute and use Case statement to put it in one of the four buckets. Once that is done do a query , grouping by the new column-- bucket.