# Oracle interval arithmetic for aggregating rows

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, intervals

I'm writing a query to group rows by their timestamps into aggregation blocks.  The query parameters include the start time `start` of the first aggregation block and a positive integer `period` which is the length of each and every aggregation block in minutes.  Given a row's timestamp `row_stamp`, which is later than `start`, I want to calculate its `block_start` such that

- `block_start` <= `row_stamp` < `block_start` + `period` minutes, and
- `block_start` = `start` + (N * `period` minutes) where N is a nonnegative integer

It's easy enough to find `row_stamp - start`, which appears to be an interval.  I figure I'll want `block_start` to be either `start + (period minutes) * FLOOR((row_stamp - start) / (period minutes))` or `row_stamp - MOD(row_stamp - start, period minutes)`.  I know neither of these is exact syntax, but I think you see the algorithms I'm going for.  Unfortunately, it looks like neither `FLOOR` nor `MOD` works well with an interval as its first parameter.  What's the recommended way to turn an interval into a number of minutes and then, after the math, turn it back to an interval again?

My apologies for not mentioning earlier that I'm looking for the number of rows in each aggregation block.  Edited to add an example.

```
CREATE TABLE "DEV_JKNIGHT" ( "ROW_STAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL );
insert into dev_jknight values (TIMESTAMP '2022-06-27 14:27:00');
insert into dev_jknight values (TIMESTAMP '2022-06-27 14:32:00');
insert into dev_jknight values (TIMESTAMP '2022-06-27 14:33:00');
insert into dev_jknight values (TIMESTAMP '2022-06-27 15:01:00');
insert into dev_jknight values (TIMESTAMP '2022-06-27 16:32:00');
```

Suppose the query parameters are a start time of '2022-06-27 14:15:00' and a period of 15 minutes.  Then the aggregation blocks are as follows.  The first begins at the specified start time and lasts for the period number of minutes.  The next block starts immediately after the first one ends and lasts the same length.

- 14:15:00 - 14:30:00, June 27
- 14:30:00 - 14:45:00, June 27
- 14:45:00 - 15:00:00, June 27
- 15:00:00 - 15:15:00, June 27
- and so on

If I run the query with those parameters, then I'm looking for these four rows of output.

- Block start = '2022-06-27 14:15:00', count = "1"
- Block start = '2022-06-27 14:30:00', count = "2"
- Block start = '2022-06-27 15:00:00', count = "1"
- Block start = '2022-06-27 16:30:00', count = "1"

The first row of output indicates that there is one, and only one, dev_jknight row in the aggregation block which starts at 14:15:00 -- namely, the row at 14:27:00.

The second row of output indicates that there are two dev_jknight rows in the aggregation block which starts at 14:30:00 -- the rows at 14:32 and 14:33.

Because there are zero dev_jknight rows in the third aggregation block (14:45 - 15:00), there is no output row for it.

The last two rows of output indicate that there is one dev_jknight rows in the aggregation block which starts at 15:00 and one in the block which starts at 16:30.

Thank you for your patience while I clarified this.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)? Please provide some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Please  [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the expected output for that sample data; and an (English, not code) explanation of how to calculate the expected output from the input.

Comment: This function may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284271/grouping-set-of-data-by-15-minutes-intervals/40285359#40285359 Query would be `SELECT ... GROUP BY MakeInterval(TIMESTAMP '2022-06-27 14:15:00', INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)`

Answer (score 0):

> Turn an interval into a number of minutes?

Use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT   EXTRACT(DAY    FROM value) * 24 * 60
       + EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM value) * 60
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM value)
       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM value) / 60 AS minutes
FROM   (
  SELECT INTERVAL '1 12:34:56.789' DAY TO SECOND AS value
  FROM   DUAL
);
```

Which outputs:

> | MINUTES |
> | --- |
> | 2194.946483333333333333333333333333333333 |

---

> and then turn it back to an interval again?

Multiply a 1 minute interval by the number of minutes:

```sql
SELECT INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * 2194.94648333333 AS interval_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

or, use the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function:

```sql
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(2194.94648333333, 'MINUTE') AS interval_value FROM DUAL;
```

> | INTERVAL_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | +000000001 12:34:56.789000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2a9050791bd8f3e0037a2f1a8a6fad56)*