Grouping 5 Minutes Interval To 15 Minutes When The Start Of The Interval Is Not Midnight
Using SQL or PL/SQL How do I sum up 5 minute intervals to 15 minute where the start of the interval is not midnight?
For example below the start of the interval is 00:05, 00:20, 00:35, and 00:50
Given these intervals and their values:



Interval
Value




00:05
2


00:10
3


00:15
7


00:20
1


00:25
7


00:30
8


00:35
9


00:40
10


00:45
3


00:50
1


00:55
2


00:00
3



The desired result:



Interval
Values




00:15
12


00:30
16


00:45
22


00:00
6




For a more generic proposal have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284271/grouping-set-of-data-by-15-minutes-intervals/40285359#40285359

You can use:
SELECT MOD(CEIL((DATE '1970-01-01' + inter - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*4), 4) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AS inter,
       SUM(value) AS total
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY MOD(CEIL((DATE '1970-01-01' + inter - DATE '1970-01-01')*24*4), 4);

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (inter, value) AS
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:05' HOUR TO MINUTE, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:20' HOUR TO MINUTE, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:25' HOUR TO MINUTE, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:40' HOUR TO MINUTE, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:45' HOUR TO MINUTE, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:50' HOUR TO MINUTE, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:55' HOUR TO MINUTE, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 3 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



INTER
TOTAL




+000000000 00:15:00.000000000
12


+000000000 00:30:00.000000000
16


+000000000 00:45:00.000000000
22


+000000000 00:00:00.000000000
6



fiddle

This can be done by grouping the data per interval using a case statement. First extract the minute part using SUBSTR (note that "00" needs to be treated separately), then assign a bucket to each value, then sum and group by bucket:
sample data:
create table 
 t(interval,value) as 
(
select '00:05',     2 from dual union all 
select '00:10',     3 from dual union all 
select '00:15',     7 from dual union all 
select '00:20',     1 from dual union all 
select '00:25',     7 from dual union all 
select '00:30',     8 from dual union all 
select '00:35',     9 from dual union all 
select '00:40',     10 from dual union all 
select '00:45',     3 from dual union all 
select '00:50',     1 from dual union all 
select '00:55',     2 from dual union all 
select '00:00',     3 from dual 
);

Table T created.

SELECT 
          CASE 
            WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN '15' 
            WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN '30' 
            WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 31 AND 45 THEN '45'
            WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 46 AND 59 THEN '00' 
            WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) = 0 THEN '00' 
          END as bucket, 
          SUM(value) 
  FROM t 
  GROUP BY   
      CASE 
        WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN '15' 
        WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 16 AND 30 THEN '30' 
        WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 31 AND 45 THEN '45'
        WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) BETWEEN 46 AND 59 THEN '00' 
        WHEN substr(interval,instr(interval,':') + 1) = 0 THEN '00' 
      END
ORDER BY 1;


BU SUM(VALUE)
-- ----------
00          6
15         12
30         16
45         22

